# pivot_table aggfunc by 1 index, when there are multiple indexes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe (df1) that looks like the following:
[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrfzQ.png)

And want to pivot the data to look like this:
[df_desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR58v.png)

I've been trying many iterations of the following (and pandas groupby) and am stumped:
`df_desired = pd.pivot_table(df1, values='cost', index=['date','name'], aggfunc=np.sum)`

Since there are two indexes, it is aggregating at the 'date', 'name' level.  I instead want to aggregate (sum) 'cost' at the 'date' level only.

Is there a way to tell the function I want to sum 'cost' by 'date', without removing 'name' from the pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, whether this a use-case that would be easily provided by Pandas out of the box. You have something there like "group the date" which normally leaves a single row for the 9/1, 9/2 and so on. For the cost, this works as you will have a single value for that, i.e. the sum, but for the name then you want this group again expanded.

I found a solution that somehow doesn't feel right:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, "John"], [1, 2, "Jeff"], [1, 2, "Larry"], [2, 5, "Susi"], [2, 5, "Sally"], [3, 4, "Joe"], [3, 4, "Bob"]], columns=["date", "cost", "name"])
df.groupby(["date"], as_index=False).agg({"cost": sum, "name": lambda x: x}).explode(["name"]).set_index(["date", "cost", "name"])
```

The problem: It is only consisting of Index columns and no value actually, but maybe you can go ahead from there.

What I'm doing there is first, I group by the date and to sum up the cost and pack the names in a list. By exploding it I move every name in their own lines again. By setting the index on all the columns, I take care that all the duplicates for the cost will be removed and there is only one value at the top. This, however, will probably fail as soon as you have a name multiple times.

Output: [image]

If you want a version, that is not so beautiful but works, you could try this here instead, which should work in any case:

```
df.groupby("date", as_index=False).agg({"cost": "sum", "name": lambda x: x}).explode("name")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much and sorry for all the comment/deletes as I'm working through this!  I got your code to work exactly as you have it written, but am unable to replicate it with my Dataframe.  My Dataframe generates NaN in the name column instead of exploding out the names like your example does.  Upon closer inspection, the glaring difference I see is that my df index does not have repeating numbers like yours does aligning with the date.  example: how would I modify this code to work if your df index was [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] instead of the current [0,0,0,1,1,2,2]?

Comment: Alternatively, I am also trying to reindex my df so that I have repeating indexes for each date (to match your example to see if that works), but I'm not finding that to be an easy solution. It just reindexes it as 1,2,3,etc based on row, regardless of the value in the date column :/. I appreciate any additional help guidance! thanks so much!

Comment: @akaJasonK Could you maybe give some code so I can see your df? That exploding it leads to NaN values in the name sounds strange, so maybe you have something other than as it looks like in this Excel example. And what exactly do you mean with repeating numbers in the index? The last of my images is the result of the operation, not my input data. I don't think, that there the index is realy relevant anymore if you just focus on the data. 
I think if you can provide this example df as it actually looks for you, I can help much better.

Comment: here is a subset of my df to help recreate: ```df_test = pd.DataFrame( {'date': {3: '10/28', 11: '10/18', 17: '10/25', 21: '10/15', 33: '10/28', 36: '10/25', 40: '10/19', 44: '10/28'}, 'cost': {3: 6, 11: 6, 17: 6, 21: 6, 33: 6, 36: 6, 40: 6, 44: 6}, 'name': {3: 'Sara Zelmer', 11: 'Tim Hindro', 17: 'Judy Semicko', 21: 'Max Relltin', 33: 'Linda Snomick', 36: 'Kelli Rocin', 40: 'Jody Lemin', 44: 'Kim Listenton'}} )```

Comment: When I try to run your code directly on my original df (created from a csv import), I get NaN in the name column for any record that has more than 1 name rolled up to the date (10/25 and 10/28 if this example df).  In generating this data frame code snippet for you, I then tried to re-create a new df using the same code.  When I run your code on that, it works correctly..  I'm super confused as to why.  I used .info() method and the column data types are the same! hmm I guess I have a workaround at least